# convert .htaccess to web.config iis 10

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite, web-config

Good evening, I should convert this .htaccess file to web.config, I tried to import it into UrlRewrite but when I open the pages it gives me 404, and I need .php at the end, I would like to remove it for all the pages present

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^p/(.*)$/?$ post.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^register register.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^login login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^u messages.php [NC,L]
```

I rewrote all the urls, the only one I can't rewrite is the url that generates post registration, which would be this `https://example.com/u/username/view` (view refers to a page called `messages.php`) and the starting code is this:

```
    //save user data to DB
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_users (username,password,email) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $statement->execute(array($username,md5($password),$email));
    $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
    header("location: ".BASE_URL.'u/'.$username.'/view');
}else{
    header("location: ".BASE_URL);
}
```

and the code in `.htaccess` is this:

```
RewriteRule ^ u messages.php [NC, L]
```

Comment: These rules are not complete by themselves and would result in a rewrite loop (so they cannot be translated literally). The regex in the first rule is also "incorrect". The trailing `/?$` is redundant (which probably isn't the intention). It would be far better to state in natural language what it is you are trying to do (and show you attempt in IIS) - as it stands, your question requires an "expert" in both Apache config and IIS.

Comment: After converting your .htaccess file, what are your rules? Whether it meets the requirements of IIS rewrite rules？

Comment: The URL rewrite module can convert Apache mod_rewrite rules into functionally equivalent IIS URL rewrite rules. However, due to architectural differences between Apache and IIS, not all mod_rewrite rules can be converted. It is strongly recommended that you study the mod_rewrite ruleset until you understand its capabilities before starting the conversion process. Note that only rules that follow the Apache mod_rewrite syntax can be converted. Any other format or incorrectly formatted rewrite rules will not be recognized or will be converted incorrectly.

Comment: I rewrote all the urls, the only one I can't rewrite is the url that generates post registration, which would be this https://example.org/u/username/view (view refers to a page called messages.php ) and the starting code is this "header ("location:" .BASE_URL.'u /'.$_ SESSION ['user'] ['username']. '/ view');"

Comment: @Lorenzo You need to update your question with all the additional information. In your comment above you've not stated what that URL should be rewritten to?